# ListView item state color

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to change the background color of listview during item selection and it's various state. And I have wrote this markup:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

The problem is - my  desied color is applied in every state of the list item except the post selection of the listitem. I mean when an user select it and immediate after the touch, it shows the default blue color for some millisecond. Am I missing to handle any state?

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

please have a try, hope can help u.

Comment: how do u use this selector?  and you list item view's background is this selector or not? do u set your list item layout's background attribute?